# Scrape tr links using attrs

Tags: web-scraping, tr

I have a problem with this page, when I try to scrape all tomorrow matches, it scrapes all of yesterday, today and tomorrow. I notice that what I need contains data-def="1"

`<tr data-dt="20,7,2023,1,00" **data-def**="0">`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/next/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')

matches = soup.find_all("tr", attrs={'data-def':'1'})
for match in matches:
    link = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match.a.get('href')
    print(link)
```

I appreciate any way to scrape all the links of tomorrow matches, thanks

Comment: soup.find_all('tr', {"data-def":1}) meaning attr should be set to integer and not string.